# Does an aggregate type imply that it is also standard layout?

Tags: c++, types, language-lawyer, std

Does an aggregate type (`std::is_aggregate_v<T> == true`) imply that the type is also standard layout (`std::is_standard_layout_v<T> == true`) or not? My intuition is that the answer is yes, but I'm not entirely convinced about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not. For a class type to be standard layout, all of its non-static members must themselves be standard layout. But the same recursive requirement is not imposed on aggregates. So a simple counter example

```
struct bar {
  virtual ~bar() {}
};

struct foo {
    bar b;
};
```

`foo` is an aggregate, but it is not standard layout.

Comment: Then the two things has nothing related. You can be standard layout, or aggregate, none, or both.

Comment: @plasmacel - Yes, they are orthogonal. Aggregates are just clumps of data, and they may or may not have standard layout.

Comment: I think I confused aggregates with trivial types. Do you know a counter example where a trivial type is not standard layout?

Comment: @plasmacel - In the previous example `bar`. If I was to add another virtual member function, and removed the d'tor then it would become a trivial type, but still not standard layout.

Comment: What about aggregate and trivial? Sounds like trivial implies aggregate.

Comment: @plasmacel - A trivial type is allowed to have a deleted default constructor, thus making it a non-aggregate.

Comment: Seems like gcc with `-std=c++17` allows deleted default constructor on aggregates: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/efba6e6c7cbf6632

Answer (score 3):

No.  Imagine you have a setup like

```
struct A
{
    int a;
};

struct B : A
{

};

struct C : B
{
    int c;
};
```

Here `A`, `B` and `C` are all aggregates, but only `A` and `B` are standard layout.